# NIB-related crash on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, exception, xib

I'm having a problem I was hoping you could help me with.

My app, which is made for iPhone but not iPad, has started crashing when I try to run it on the iPad at all. I get this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<UIApplication 0x11f0b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value 
coding-compliant for the key firstLineField.'
```

`firstLineField` is a UITextField that is in an XIB file. The stack reveals that this has been called by `[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile]`, before any of my code runs. Do you guys have any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks for your help,

Luke

Addendum: Here's my stack trace.

```
#0  0x3286ca1c in __pthread_kill
#1  0x304a33ba in pthread_kill
#2  0x3049bbfe in abort
#3  0x35d09a6a in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler
#4  0x365f9072 in _objc_terminate
#5  0x35d07e3c in __cxxabiv1::__terminate
#6  0x35d07e90 in std::terminate
#7  0x35d07f60 in __cxa_throw
#8  0x365f7c8a in objc_exception_throw
#9  0x358a43cc in -[NSException raise]
#10 0x351f3eda in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:]
#11 0x351ac9ca in _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter
#12 0x351ac216 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]
#13 0x3518e42e in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:]
#14 0x3219b8de in -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect]
#15 0x3583cd7a in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:]
#16 0x3583c99c in -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
#17 0x3219a846 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
#18 0x3219be08 in -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:]
#19 0x31fc64cc in -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile]
#20 0x31fc0b08 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
#21 0x31f957d6 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
#22 0x31f95214 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
#23 0x31f94c52 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#24 0x31e6be76 in PurpleEventCallback
#25 0x3587ba96 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#26 0x3587d83e in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
#27 0x3587e60c in __CFRunLoopRun
#28 0x3580eec2 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#29 0x3580edca in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#30 0x31fbfd48 in -[UIApplication _run]
#31 0x31fbd806 in UIApplicationMain
#32 0x0000294e in main at main.m:13
```

Comment: can you paste your stack trace.

Comment: In the XIB file, the firstLineField is an outlet for a class which doesn't have it defined (anymore?), is my guess. Just a guess so commenting rather than answering though. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `UITextField` that's connected to an outlet property named `firstLineField`, but this property can't be found in the controller.

Check that `firstLineField` property is actually defined in the controller class.

Comment: firstLineField is definitely defined, and it works fine in the simulator and on the iPhone. Do you have any idea what would cause things to be different on the iPad?

Comment: Does it work on iPad simulator? And did you try to delete the app from iPad and installing it again?